# Android - Daemon process not running

Tags: gradle, gradle-daemon

I'm trying to start an android project however each time i'm faces with the same
problem of having the daemon process being unable to run.

This the second time i'm faces with the problem, in the last time it required uninstalling the android SDK & JDK and reinstalling them to solve the problem.

I've tried the following solutions as well, but they didn't work.

1. Changing the value of `org.gradle.jvmargs` in the `gradle.properties` file and restarting the project.
2. Invalidate caches and restart project.
3. Deleting the `.gradle` file from the `c:\\Users\<username>` directory and restarting the project.

Note: I've tried to figure out the error which seems from the log file to be a java.net.BindException, however I've tried searching the system for the cause of the conflict and I was unable to find it.

Below is daemon log for the run.

```
21:37:24.335 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain] Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-Xmx1536m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1256, -Duser.country=GB, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
21:37:24.436 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Native-platform posix files integration is not available. Continuing with fallback.
21:37:24.504 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.gc.GarbageCollectionMonitor] Unable to determine a garbage collection monitoring strategy for JVMStrategy{JetBrains s.r.o version 1.8.0_152-release}
21:37:24.577 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] start() called on daemon - DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ec7ab907-0ea6-4f85-a366-7546f869c296,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\BaraHashesh\.gradle\daemon,pid=7156,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1256,-Duser.country=GB,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
21:37:24.728 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Software Loopback Interface 1
21:37:24.730 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? true
21:37:24.732 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.733 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
21:37:24.734 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
21:37:24.734 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Software Loopback Interface 1
21:37:24.734 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
21:37:24.737 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.740 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.740 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
21:37:24.741 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
21:37:24.744 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.746 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.746 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:a002:fcc:38da:3a4b%eth1
21:37:24.747 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
21:37:24.747 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
21:37:24.750 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.752 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.752 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /192.168.1.110
21:37:24.752 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:7117:589d:d745:70de%wlan0
21:37:24.752 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
21:37:24.753 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
21:37:24.755 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.757 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.757 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:a9e5:17c7:fa61:1ed9%wlan1
21:37:24.757 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
21:37:24.757 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
21:37:24.760 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.762 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.763 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
21:37:24.763 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
21:37:24.765 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.767 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? false
21:37:24.767 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
21:37:24.769 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.772 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? false
21:37:24.773 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
21:37:24.775 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.777 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.777 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
21:37:24.777 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface TAP-Windows Adapter V9
21:37:24.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.781 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.782 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface TAP-Windows Adapter V9
21:37:24.782 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS
21:37:24.784 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.786 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.786 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS
21:37:24.786 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #2
21:37:24.788 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.790 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.790 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #2
21:37:24.790 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS #2
21:37:24.793 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.795 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.795 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS #2
21:37:24.795 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #3
21:37:24.797 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.799 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.799 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #3
21:37:24.799 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS #3
21:37:24.802 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.804 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.805 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS #3
21:37:24.805 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
21:37:24.807 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.808 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.809 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /192.168.124.1
21:37:24.809 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:b5ff:3c7d:c72a:75f%eth8
21:37:24.809 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
21:37:24.809 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
21:37:24.811 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.813 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.813 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /192.168.229.1
21:37:24.813 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:8ddc:1330:e8e6:4394%eth9
21:37:24.813 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
21:37:24.813 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
21:37:24.816 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.818 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? false
21:37:24.818 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:16e%net4
21:37:24.819 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
21:37:24.821 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.823 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.823 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
21:37:24.823 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
21:37:24.825 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.827 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.827 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:a4b9:b26:e0d1:5677%wlan2
21:37:24.827 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
21:37:24.827 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.831 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.834 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.834 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.834 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
21:37:24.837 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.839 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.839 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
21:37:24.839 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.841 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.844 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.844 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.844 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.846 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.849 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.849 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.849 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000
21:37:24.852 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000
21:37:24.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
21:37:24.855 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
21:37:24.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
21:37:24.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.861 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.861 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
21:37:24.861 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.863 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.865 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.865 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.865 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.867 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.868 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.869 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.869 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
21:37:24.871 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.873 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.874 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
21:37:24.874 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
21:37:24.876 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.878 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.878 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
21:37:24.878 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.881 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.884 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.884 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.884 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.887 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
21:37:24.891 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.893 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.893 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
21:37:24.893 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
21:37:24.894 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.896 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.896 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
21:37:24.896 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:24.898 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
21:37:24.900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
21:37:24.900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
21:37:25.000 [ERROR] [system.err] 
21:37:25.001 [ERROR] [system.err] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
21:37:25.002 [ERROR] [system.err] 
21:37:25.002 [ERROR] [system.err] * What went wrong:
21:37:25.002 [ERROR] [system.err] java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
21:37:25.002 [ERROR] [system.err] 
21:37:25.003 [ERROR] [system.err] * Try:
21:37:25.003 [ERROR] [system.err] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
21:37:25.005 [ERROR] [system.err] 
21:37:25.005 [ERROR] [system.err] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Daemon vm is shutting down... The daemon has exited normally or was terminated in response to a user interrupt.
21:37:25.008 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Removing daemon address: null
21:37:25.047 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:37:25.050 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
21:37:25.054 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

Comment: are you using windows 10?

Comment: No, I'm using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 users

Open up task manager and find adb.exe and end its process

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1, there is no such process currently running on my device.

Comment: I think you are having 2 diff versions of java installed. So just uninstall both and try installing version 8 alone.

Answer (score 0):

this means, that Gradle cannot connect to the daemon process over the local loopback interface (alias the `Software Loopback Interface`, as it is called in the above log). therefore, check the firewall rules for `127.0.0.1`... or maybe disable the firewall once, for a test.

it merely complains, that ...

```
Address already in use: **bind**
```

and then ...

```
Removing daemon address: **null**
```

because it could not connect to `127.0.0.1` nor any other adapter it tried to connect the daemon on.

Comment: I've just tried turning off the windows fire wall, it didn't work. I've been trying to find a solution for over two weeks and still haven't managed to find one. The only thing I know is that I started experiencing this problem right after I started developing Angular 6 Projects